# Connect wirelessly to WPA2-Enterprise network via shell

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, wpa-supplicant, wpa

I need to connect to a WPA2-Enterprise connection wirelessly through the shell but cannot figure out how to do it. I have researched and have found many results for WPA2-Personal and even WPA2-Enterprise GUI, but nothing successful on WPA2-Enterprise with the command line.